# React Leaflet map rendering all over the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am fairly new to React and Leaflet. I have gotten Leaflet working just fine in a simple HTML page. So now I am trying to make a more dynamic site by using React.

The problem I am running into is I can get it to render sort-of. The map appears all over the page in chunks. I put an h1 above and a simple div with text below the map dev and you can see it render randomly past the lower text. its also not one contiguous map.

I'm using React v18.2.0 with React Leaflet at 4.2.1 with Leaflet 1.9.3.

Here is my app code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>See my map</h1>
      <MapContainer center={[45.4, -75.7]} zoom={12}scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
      </MapContainer>
      <div>After map report</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]
[image]

I would love for any advice on what is going on and what I can do to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I figured this out a little too quickly after posting. I was digging through the posted issues in Github and found this: https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/1052

Apparently, the instructions I was using as a guide for this completely lacked the fact that I need to import the Leaflet css. Ugh.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You saved me a bunch of time.